# Alternative to enquote_literal for string containing single quote

Tags: sql, oracle

I am bound to use `dbms_assert.enquote_literal` to enquote string. The string is schema name which is unknown to me as it is coming as a parameter to my function. The only thing I know is that a schema name may contain single quote. For such strings enquote_literal fails with `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`. Is there any alternative that I can use in place of enquote_literal that gives the same output as enquote_literal.

Comment: before using `dbms_assert.enquote_literal`, can you not do a `replace(text,'''',''))` or do you need the single quotes in your final text ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Yes I need single quote in final text.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good solution, but an easy solution is

```
REPLACE(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(REPLACE(text,'''','''''')),
    '''''','''');
```

Input Text

```
hello'world
```

Output Text

```
'hello'world'
```

If you don't need the quote to appear even once

```
dbms_assert.enquote_literalreplace(text,'''',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'q' quotes [Read here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311).

```
select q'['<you string>']' from dual;
```

Demo

```
SQL> select q'['Hello'workddl']' Col from dual;

COL
--------------
'Hello'workddl'
```

Comment: like dbms_assert.enquote_literal, how safe it is from sql injection attack?

Comment: Also I cannot use it in plsql block provide the string is coming as function parameter and is not a hardcoded one.

Comment: @user1612078. Did you read the link i shared. Didn't you find the usage in PLSQL. Also SQL injection comes to picture when you try your hands with Dynamic SQL. I dont see you using dynamic sql anywhere in your question